# Event Listeners vs Rest Calls

Tags: performance, rest, design-patterns, architecture, dom-events

I have multiple applications/microservices.

I am developing a kind of interface where user can have a single unified interface for all the applications and for that I am developing a kind of envelope application which will show all the other applications in `iframe` inside itself.

Now most of the applications need to communicate with each other and as I already mentioned that they are microservices, so I am using `rest` calls for communication between them.

But I've also used `event listeners` to share data between them. And that works fine too. But I am not very sure what can be the impact of using that. So my question is can I normally use event listeners for communications as we normally do when we have applications inside ifram etc ?

What are the pros and cons of using `rest call` vs `events` ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what Martin Fowler called [smart endpoints and dumb pipes](https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html#SmartEndpointsAndDumbPipes).

As for which is better: there's no clear "winner", because those aren't mutually exclusive. They serve different semantic purposes (although may provide the same results) and can be used together within one application.

Only thing you have to keep in mind that event model is inherently asynchronous and you should treat it this way. Surely you can come up with some SLA to make messaging seem synchronous or create synchronous-like effects on front-end, but still.

As for pros and cons, I can give you few statements which might help you decide when to use which technique:

- **Coupling** - comparing reactive event-driven model and plain API, you can say that API gives you tighter coupling as you must follow some predefined interface. Messages aren't so strict in that regard, but they can be if needed
- **Scaling** - event-driven model is scaled much easier: create a few more workers and you're done. This statelessness can become a problem, though - you might need same worker to process specific events and that could lead to quite difficult queuing architecture
- **Error handling** - implementing error handling in REST API could be as easy as throwing appropriate error and be done with it. But what if you need to retry failed request to external service? Should it be done on API back-end side or it must be client-side? What if you need different type of retry logic for each request? Your API might become too smart, which is usually a bad thing
- **Blocking vs Non-blocking** - do you have a contingency plan if your service doesn't meet expected SLA? Blocking might be a problem too, but at least you can control the flow and monitor execution process
- **Resiliency** - you might loose valuable data if your API crashes mid-execution. Queuing allows you to wait until workers become available again

Those are just highlights, this list is not final in any way. Both techniques entail different complexities within your application. Best tip here would be to use qualitative statements (kinda like those above), common sense and KISS to decide which is more suitable for your case (or maybe both?).